# How to make all except the first tab closable in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a tabbed menu and I want all except the 1st tab which is the menu tab closable. Much like the yahoo mail GUI. Inbox and Contacts tabs are not closable while the subsequent tabs are closable.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery(function() {
       var mytabs = jQuery("#tabs").tabs({tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>"});

       jQuery( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live( "click", function() {
         var index = jQuery( "li", mytabs ).index( jQuery( this ).parent() );
         $tabs.tabs( "remove", index );
       });

 });

<script type="text/javascript">

function openComplaintDiv(complaint, complaintNo,demographic_no) {
var htmlContent= "complaint = '"+complaint+"'complaintNo ='"+complaintNo+"'for user = '"+demo_no+"'";
jQuery("#tabs").tabs().tabs('add', '#vtab_'+complaint.replace(" ","_"), complaint.replace(" ","_"));
jQuery("#vtab_"+complaint.replace(" ","_")).html(htmlContent);
return false;
}

</script>

<style>
    #tabs li .ui-icon-close { float: left; margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; cursor: pointer; }
</style>

<html>
    <body>
            <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#mainMenu">Home</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="mainMenu">

        <div id="addTab" onclick="addNewComplaintDiv();"><a style="padding:6px 6px 6px 17px;text-decoration:none;position:relative" href="#" id="addTab_1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <span style="position:absolute;top:4px;left:1px" class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
            Add new complaint
        </a></div>
        <table class="normal">
        <% 

            for (Integer key : complaintMap.keySet()) {  %> 
            <tr><td style="height:50px;"><div id="openComplaint_<%=key%>" onclick="openComplaintDiv('<%=complaintMap.get(key)%>',<%=key%>,<%=demo_no%>);"><a style="padding:6px 6px 6px 17px;text-decoration:none;position:relative" href="#" id="addTab_1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                    <%=complaintMap.get(key)%>
                </a></div> </td></tr>
            <%  } %>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This code makes all tabs closable but I don't want the "mainMenu" tab to be closable. Also, I'm adding a new tab each time a "complaint div" in the "Main menu" tab is clicked. I actually want to create a new tab if it's not already created and select the corresponding tab if it is already created. How can I do this?

Comment: replace all your jQuerys with $s...... that wont fix your problem but i don't know why you wouldn't do that

Comment: There's prototype on my page so I have to use jQuery instead of "$".

Answer (score 0):

On init, use

```
disabled: [1]

var mytabs = jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    disabled: [1]
});
```

Comment: thanks that worked....but how can I "add" a tab depending on whether it exists or not. If you see my code, I am creating clickable `div`s for the number of entries in "complaintMap". If the div is already created, I want that div to be opened instead of creating a duplicate div.

Comment: What criteria are you using when creating new tabs to determine if one exists or not? If you are creating a "new" tab, why would there be a duplicate? Creating a new one should just append and increment the existing index.

anyways, there is this method to call: .tabs( "add" , url , label , [index] )

Comment: I have a list of clickable items in my "Home" tab which when clicked open in a new tab. `jQuery("#tabs").tabs().tabs('add', '#childTab_'+comp_joined, comp_joined);` This code creates a new tab without checking if it exists or not. Would adding the `[index]` option solve this problem?